# How to change settings for camera profile.xml qualcomm Vuforia AR in Unity3D?

Tags: xml, camera, profile

anyone know how to setting camera profile xml qualcomm vuforia in unity3d, i got warning massage in camera scipt behavior like this

webcam profile not found! unfortunately there is no profile for your webcam model: "HP Webcam 101 ". How to fix this warning, please help me?

Comment: How you fixed this issue, right now i am facing the same trouble.

Comment: Have same problem. 
I created completely new project, and camera works there. No luck with previous project unforunately.
I noticed that WebcamProfiles folder in new project moved from Assets\Editor\QCAR to Assets\Vuforia\Editor, but copying it there manually in old project did not help.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aholla/Vuforia-Test-Unity/blob/master/Assets/Editor/QCAR/WebcamProfiles/profiles.xml

you can create a custom profile by adding the above xml script